# How can I update only that attribute which I want to?

Tags: javascript, node.js

how you see it, it works fine but it works only if I type everything in.

So for example I want to change only my password how can I implement that.

That you know in my Frontend my userID is always given and can´t be updated I don´t if it´s significant

my update function :

```
exports.update = async (req,res,next) => {

  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

      const result = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
              userID: req.body.userID,
          },
          {
              userName: req.body.userName,
            
          },
          {
            password: hashedPassword
          },
          
          {
              upsert: true,
              new: true
          }
      )
      res.send(result);
  }catch(err){
      res.status(401).json(err);
  }
}
```

How I request it :

```
###
PUT http://localhost:8080/user/
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}
Content-Type: application/json

{

     "userID": "test",
    "userName": "test",
    "password": "12345"
    

}
```

But I want maybe only this :

```
###
PUT http://localhost:8080/user/
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}
Content-Type: application/json

{

     "userID": "",
    "userName": "",
    "password": "12345"
    

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. 
it is very unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: There's no User in  Node. If it's Mongoose model, the question should state this explicitly

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only update the password, and since I assume your userId is unique, it's as simple as that:

```
const result = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
              userID: req.body.userID,
          },
          {
            password: hashedPassword
          },
          
          {
              upsert: true,
              new: true
          }
      );
```

EDIT: the prototype of `findOneAndUpdate` function takes 2 mandatory parameters and two optionals, in order: `filter`, an object used in the **find** part of the function, `update`, an object with the keys/values to update for the object found, and `options` where you can specify a bunch of options (like `upsert` and `new`). Eventually, a callback can be given to it, but you're already using async/await so it's not that useful...

Please note that this function will **only update** what you give it in the `update` parameter, so regarding your comments, my code is still valid. Read more [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html). Also [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) for the prototype of the function.

---

Further explanation regarding comments:

> update, an object with the keys/values to update for the object found

This sentence explains it all. You only need to pass to this object what you **need to change**, that's it. For example:

```
// to modify ONLY the password

const result = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        userID: req.body.userID,
    }, {          
        password: hashedPassword
    }, {
        upsert: true,
        new: true
    }
);

// to modify ONLY the username
const result = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        userID: req.body.userID,
    }, {          
        userName: "my_super_username"
    }, {
        upsert: true,
        new: true
    }
);

// to modify BOTH the username and the password
const result = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        userID: req.body.userID,
    }, {          
        userName: "my_super_username",
        password: hashedPassword
    }, {
        upsert: true,
        new: true
    }
);
```

Now, if your password is undefined when you only change the `userName` key, that must come from somewhere else in the code and since I only have so much, I can't help further.

Comment: No not only the password. If I want to change the password I don't want to be forced to change the username too

Comment: So I want to choose which I want to change ..

Comment: Edited my answer but it was valid even before the edit. Changing the password will **NOT** change the username. You were using the function with 4 parameters, which is not valid (well, it technically **is** valid, but not the way you were using it).

Comment: So how can I implement the filter object in ?

Comment: I corrected a typo: `filter, AN (instead of AND) object used [...]`. You don't seem to understand. The filter object is already there, in my code as well as yours. It is `{ userID: req.body.userID }`. The `update` object is `{ password: hashedPassword },`. The `option` object is `{ upsert: true, new: true }`. I can't grasp what you don't understand.

Comment: So if I want to update my userName I dont have to type my passwort ?

Comment: I tried it and if I want to update my userName I can´t do it because password is undefined then

Comment: Probably because you typed: `{password: ""}`. That's not how it works. I'll edit my answer to explain better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240751/discussion-between-gaetan-boyals-and-basics-typer).

Comment: But I can´t let password empty if I let "password" : this way  it says unexpected token